# Replacing Periods in DF's Columns

Tags: python, pandas, replace

---

### Replacing Periods in DF's Columns

I was wondering if there was an efficient way to replace periods in pandas dataframes without having to iterate through each row and call.replace() on the row.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'column':['Sam M.']})
df.column = df.column.replace('.','')

print df
```

Result

```
   column

0  None
```

Desired Result

```
   column

0  Sam M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['column'].str.replace('.', '', regex=False)

0    Sam M
Name: column, dtype: object
```

Comment: I read that changing regex to False only makes the statement true if the string has the whole replacement frame. I didn't think this would be a problem though because '.' is a single character. In rereading the pandas module for pandas.Series.str.replace, I realized that '.' in Regex True is interpreted as any character, can you explain why?

Comment: @SamMahle That's for `DataFrame.replace`. For `Series.str.replace`, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Because `.` is a regex special character so put `'\'` front of it then it will be good:

Solution:

```
df['column'].str.replace('\.','')
```

Example:

```
df['column']=df['column'].str.replace('\.','')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   column
0  Sam M
```

Comment: Of course, this is a valid alternative. But if regex is not needed, it's best to unset the regex switch and let the replacement be pure string-based.

Comment: Why does normal python string replacement not factor in this Regex, but pandas.Series.str.replace does?

Comment: @SamMahle Because pandas uses regex for a lot of stuff, regex is useful (so make pandas more useful), if there is a Series, you want to remove all integers from all strings, do `series.str.replace('\d+','')`